# How can I make a view go full screen like the YouTube app?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avplayerlayer

I have made a subclass of UIView that automatically adds a AVPlayerLayer along with the video controls. I need to implement a full screen button that takes the UIView and rotates it into fullscreen just like the YouTube app. The problem is the UIView does not cover the whole screen. I have a XLPagerTab below the UIView that contains the overview and stuff for the video.

This is my code to make the UIView full screen. It is inside the VideoPlayer Class which is a subclass of UIView. isExpanded is a boolean to know the state, smallScreenCenter is used to store the initial center of the view to switch back to the small screen.

```
func fullScreenTapped() {
    
    if !isExpanded {
        //Expand the video
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            self.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.5)
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
            self.layoutSubviews()
            
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //Shrink the video again
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            //16 x 9 is the aspect ratio of all HD videos
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.center = self.smallScreenCenter!
            
            let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 9 / 16
            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height)
            self.frame = videoPlayerFrame
            
            self.layoutSubviews()
            
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    isExpanded = !isExpanded
    
}
```

The view rotates and all but does not cover the whole screen, it just looks like this.

[image: After tapping on fullscreen]

Is the XLPagerTab interfering with the fullscreen? I am confused.

Comment: are you talking about full screen or rotation? your video suggests that you would like the whole screen to rotate and it has nothing to do with full screen. Regarding the rotation, did you set `Support Interface Orientations` for your project? does this view have some custom code related to rotation? do other screens rotate as expected?

Comment: I am not trying to make the whole screen to rotate, just make it seem like it rotated and make the video cover the screen by rotating it. 
PS: It now sounds like a better idea to just rotate the screen, but I haven't really looked into it.

Comment: Do you expect the video to just stretch to available space? I mean the video has a certain aspect ratio, it won't look good...

Comment: No since the whole view rotates, i want it to maintain an aspect ratio to fit the rotated view.